Proof for particular solution of a linear system
I'm trying to understand the a proof for the following Lemma, from a section of the Linear Algebra wikibook on Nonhomogeneous Systems. The wikibook is based on Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon.

Lemma 3.8
For a linear system, where $\vec{p} \:$  is any particular solution,
the solution set equals this set.
$\{\vec{p}+\vec{h} \mid \text{ $\vec{h}$ satisfies the associated homogeneous system} \}$

The proof then states:

We will show mutual set inclusion, that any solution to the system is
in the above set and that anything in the set is a solution to the
system.
For set inclusion the first way, that if a vector solves the system
then it is in the set described above,  assume that $\vec{s}$ solves
the system.  Then $\vec{s}-\vec{p}$ solves the associated homogeneous
system since for each equation index $i$,
$$ \begin{multline*}   a_{i,1}(s_1-p_1)+\cdots+a_{i,n}(s_n-p_n) \\  
=(a_{i,1}s_1+\cdots+a_{i,n}s_n)          -(a_{i,1}p_1+\cdots+a_{i,n}p_n)
=d_i-d_i =0 \end{multline*} $$
where $p_j$ and $s_j$ are the $j$-th components of $\vec{p}$ and
$\vec{s}$. Express $\vec{s}$ in the required $\vec{p}+\vec{h}$ form by
writing $\vec{s}-\vec{p}$ as $\vec{h}$.

My questions are about $d_i$.

It appears $d_i = (a_{i,1}s_1+\cdots+a_{i,n}s_n)$ and $d_i = (a_{i,1}p_1+\cdots+a_{i,n}p_n)$.  Why is this the case?
Is there some meaning behind using the letter $d$.  Or is this likely an arbitrary choice?

I'm fairly rusty with Linear Algebra and Proofs, so simple answers are likely to be preferred over complex ones.


This is because $s$ and $p$ are both assumed to be solutions to the system. The system is

$$\begin{cases}
a_{1, 1} x_1 + \dots + a_{1, N} x_N = d_1 \\
\vdots \\
a_{M, 1} x_1 + \dots + a_{M, N} x_N = d_M
\end{cases}$$
where $N$ is the number of variables and $M$ is the number of equations, both positive integers. Since $x = s$ and $x = p$ both solve the system, then for any equation index $i \in \{ 1, \dots, M \}$, you have
$$a_{i, 1} s_1 + \dots + a_{i, N} s_N = a_{i, 1} p_1 + \dots + a_{i, N} p_N = d_i$$

It's probably arbitrary. I have more commonly seen $b$ used. You will find that the system in (1) is equivalent to a matrix equation $A x = d$, where $A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{1, 1} & \dots & a_{1, N} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{M, 1} & \dots & a_{M, N} \end{pmatrix}$, $x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_N \end{pmatrix}$, and $d = \begin{pmatrix} d_1 \\ \vdots \\ d_M \end{pmatrix}$.

